# How to optimize this website. Need general advices

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, codeigniter, web

this is my first question here, which is regarding a specific website optimization.
A few moths ago, we launched [site] for one of our clients which is some kind of community website.

Everything works great, but now this website is getting bigger and it shows some slowness when the pages are loading.

The server specs:

- PHP 5.2.1 (i think we need to upgrade on 5.3 to make use of the new garbage collector)
- Apache 2.2
- Quad Core Xeon Processor @ 2,8 Ghz and 4 GB DDR 3 RAM.
- XCACHE 1.3 (we added this a few months ago)
- Mysql 5.1 (we are using innodb as engine)
- Codeigniter framework

Here is what we did so far and what we intend to do further :

Beside xcache, we don't really use a caching mechanism because most of the content comes live and beside this, we didn't wanted to optimize prematurely because we didn't know what to expect as far as the traffic flow.
On the other hand, we have installed memcached and we want to implement a cache system based on memcached.

Regarding the database structure, we have reached 3NF with most of our tables, and yes we have some slow queries(which we plan to optimize) but i think because the tables that produce slow queries are the one for blog comments(~44,408 rows) / user logs tracking (~725,837 rows) / user comments (~698,964 rows) etc which are quite big tables. The entire database is 697.4 MB in size for now.

Also, here are some stats for January 2011:
Monthly unique visitors: - 127.124
Monthly unique views: 4.829.252
Monthly unique visits: 242.708

Daily average:
Unique new visitors: 7.533
Unique new views : 179.680

Just let me know if you need more details.
Any advice is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Got any profiling results? What causing pages to load slow? Network? Database? 3-rd party services? What is page generation time? What page slowest of them all? What part of this page causing that?

Comment: However, I'd shoot in the dark into user logs tracking general direction...

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a magic wand that will make everything faster.  There isn't one.  First you need to identify your bottleneck.  Step through the code, get debug/trace information directly from what's running in Production if you have to.  But you need to know what's slowing you down before you can fix it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. here is some data, for example, loading a profile page shows:  Time: 0.1109 · memory: 1.17MB · Queries: 14 . One of the slowest pages, is when a user browse the member list: Time: 0.2846 · Memory: 1.19MB · Queries: 10

Comment: Those January 2011 numbers look so very strange. You're a europhile using a "." as a thousands separator? Because the paragraph above isn't. If you have only 7 daily unique visitors, you've got hardly any traffic, and performance shouldn't be of any concern at all unless you're doing something extremely intensive for them.

Comment: if "europhile" means people from Europe, then yes, i am :)

Comment: Ha. I meant the use of backward-looking decimals. Someday, the whole world needs to switch to a convention on these things. I thought compuyter people all used "," for a thousands separator. </dissappointed>

Comment: @zanlok, if you read "Unique new visitors: 7.533" as "7 visitors", how do you read "Monthly unique views: 4.829.252"?

Comment: i just copied from the website analytics service, didn't gave it too much attention.

Comment: @binary hey, I'm just saying what many other U.S.A. would probably also say. the mix was more the point, ps.

Answer (score 2):

When it come to performance issue, there is no golden rule or labelled sticky note that first tell that is related to database. Maybe what i could suggest is to do performance profiling and there are many free and paid tools over the Internet that allows you to do so.

First start of with web server layer, make sure everything is done correctly and optimized as what is be possible.

Then move on to next layer (which i assume is your database). Normally from layman perspective whenever someone mentioned InnoDB MySQL, we assume there are indexes being created to optimize and search operations. The usage of indexes also quite important because you don't want to indexing something wrong and make things worse. My advise to this is to get a DBA equivalent personnel to troubleshoot using a staging environment.

Another tricks you could possibility look at is the contents, from web page contents to database data, make sure you show/keep data where is needed only, do no store unnecessary information into database and using smart layout on the webpage. A cut down of a seconds or two might do a big difference in terms of usability and response time.

It is very hard to explain the detail here unless we have in-depth information about your application, its architecture and your environment, but above are some commonly used direction people use to troubleshoot such incident.

Good luck!

Comment: I just posted above some stats about the resources usage when a request is made:(loading a profile page shows: Time: 0.1109 · memory: 1.17MB · Queries: 14 . One of the slowest pages, is when a user browse the member list: Time: 0.2846 · Memory: 1.19MB · Queries: 10). Thanks for the general advices, i will take them into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

This site has excellent resources http://www.websiteoptimization.com/
The books that are mentioned are excellent. There are just too many techniques to list here and we do not know what you have tried so far.

Comment: The [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/) is also a great resource. It's targeted for higher-end (bigger) deployments of cluster server. Nice that it's been around for quite a while.

Comment: i am more interested in optimizing the "engines" that power the website, rather than optimizing it for SEO .

Comment: @zanlok yes i know, thank you for this, i am also a reader of that website.

Comment: Uhh, that website looks so spammy.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay guys, i have been very busy to find the issue and i did it.

Well, the problem was because of apache mostly, i had an access log of almost 300 GB which at midnight was parsed to generate webalizer stats. Mostly when this was happening the website was very very slow. I disabled webalizer for the domain, cleared the logs, and what to see, it is very fast again, doesn't matter the hour you access it.

I now only have just a few slow queries that i tend to fix today.
I also updated to CI 2.0 Reactor as suggested and started to use the memcached driver.

Who would knew that apache logs can be so problematic...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stats, I don't think you are hitting load problems... on a hunch, I would look to the database first.  [Database partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) might be a good place to start.

But you should really do some profiling of your application first.  How much time is spent in the application versus database.  Are there application methods that are using lots of time and just need some tweaking?  Are database queries not written efficiently?  Do you need more or better database indices?

Comment: Thank you for database partitioning link, i will give it a try for sure. Yes, i believe i will profile the methods inside controllers to see what is taking more time to execute, this would be an excellent starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks pretty good-- if upgrading codeigniter is an option, the new codeigniter 2.0 (reactor) adds support for memcache (New Cache driver with file system, APC and memcache support). Granted you're already using xcache, these new additions may be worth looking at.

When cache objects weren't enough for our multi-domain platform that saw huge traffic, we went the route of throwing more hardware at it-- ram, servers/database. Then we moved to database clustering to handle single account forecasted heavy load. And now switching from apache to nginx... It's a never ending battle, but what worked for us was being smart about what we cached and increasing server memory then distributing this load across servers...

Answer (score 0):

1. Cache as many database calls as you can. In my CI application I have a settings table that rarely changes, so I cache all calls made to it as I am constantly querying the settings table.
2. Cache your views and even your controllers as well. I tend to cache basically as much as I can in my CI applications and then refresh the cache when a file changes.
3. Only autoload important libraries, models and helpers. I've seen people autoload up to 10 libraries and on-top of that a few helpers and then a model. You only really need to autoload the database and session libraries if you are using them.

Regarding point number 3, are you autoloading many things in your config/autoload.php file by any chance? It might help speed things up only loading things you need in your controllers as you need them with exception of course the session and database libraries.